# Asymptotic running time in Big Theta notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Considering the below algorithm,

```
Loop1 until(i<n^2)
     Loop2 until(j<i^2)
        ....
        j=j+4
     End Loop2
     i=i*3
End Loop1
```

I think this is `Theta(n^2*log(n))`. This is correct or is the Big Theta higher than this?

Comment: `Loop until(i` rather seems a syntax error to me...

Comment: Its just an algorithm. I have not used any particular language's syntax.

Comment: @userXXX before the edit, there was no more code at all, just that: `loop until(i`. That doesn't make any sense even in pseudocode.

Comment: Oh!! I'm sorry I'm new to this and I might have done something wrong. I see "Bad Wolf" edited the question.
Thank you, @Bad Wolf

Comment: @user2781902 It just got eaten by the markdown, putting it in code blocks fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct.

Let i be near n^2, which is the case when n^2 is some power of 3.
Then the inner loop of j would run i^2 / 4 = Theta(n^4) steps.
So the total running time can't be less than Theta(n^4).

Hint: This happens to be the total running time in the end, do you see why?

Comment: Yes, I missed that the inner loop would be of n^4. So does that means this entire algorithm is Theta(n^4 * log(n)) ?

Comment: @user2781902 no, I said the entire algorithm is also Theta(n^4). To understand that, try summing up 1+2+4+...+n for n being some power of 2.